# Transfer file between servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, nodejs-stream

From a backend server want to download a file from an other backend api server:

First server that request the remote file

```
requestDownload() {
   
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream('file.mp3');

    this.httpService.get('http://MYSECONDSERVER:3000/music/download/189').subscribe(
        (result:any) => {
         
          ws.write(result.data)
        },
        (error) => {

        },
        () => {

        }
    )
  }
```

The second server that serve the file

```
async getFile(id, response) {
    let music = await this.findOne(id);
    if(music) {
      let filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../../../', music.path);
      response.set('content-type', `audio/${music.format}`);
      // response.set('accept-ranges', 'bytes');
      fs.createReadStream(filePath)
          .on('error', () => {
            response.end();
          }).pipe(response);
    }
  }
```

For both servers, I'm using the nestjs framework.

My downloaded mp3 file is broken.

Here the debug of the result object providing by the subscribe function

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: What is `this.httpService`?

Comment: provide by nestjs framework that wraps Axios package

Answer (score 0):

The result.data is not type of Buffer,

while requesting with Axios don't forget to add option to the request

```
{ responseType: 'arraybuffer' }
```

The result.data is now a correct Buffer type and can be written in a file.